# Tensorflow: Input to reshape is a tensor with 79744 values, but the requested shape has 203392

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have a small deep net which consists of 1 convolution, maxpool and several fully connected networks

The thing is that I make as training input, a batch of training data of dimensions (227 840) and labels (227 12) which seems to be trained, and then when I want to test the results with a batch of test data which less info (data 90 x 840 and labels 90 x 12) I receive this error

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 79744 values, but the requested shape has 2203392

Can anyone please give me hints where I could solve this error? I was thinking that the error was meaning to the placeholder, but the way I prepared the data in order to cope with those problems was

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,shpeData])

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,shpeLabl])

(so the None could fix this issue) however I was wrong

I could also show my code if you guys want.

Thanks

Comment: Could you demonstrate how the reshape op is applied in your graph?

Comment: Can you also explain what the numbers mean in the dimensions you've given? e.g. is training data (227 840) a single tensor with 227840 features, is it an image with dimensions 227x840, is it 840 features with a batch size of 227? Or something else?

Comment: You're on the right track with the `None` argument to `tf.placeholder`, but you probably need to update a call to `tf.reshape` elsewhere in your code. The trick is you can use `-1` in an argument to reshape in the same way you use `None` as an argument to `tf.placeholder`. Try that out; or if you share a complete example we can try to help more.

Comment: Hello everybody. Well the data I just uploaded in https://github.com/dialgop/small_deep_nn/blob/master/Cnn_Model_Martin.ipynb

Comment: Sorry, I can just edit for 5 minutes then, the thing is I reshaped the data first to 3d in order to apply the 1dconvolution and then to 4d to do the maxpool (maxpool just works with 4d dims) and then I reshaped the data again to linnear in order to work with the Fully connected neurons

@MarkMcDonald training data is a batch of data of 227 different examples with 840 features.